# Rename "stackoverflow" tag to "stackexchange"

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that a "stackoverflow" tag was recently added.  I believe "stackexchange" would be better.  Following the recommendation in [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag) I ask for a moderator with sufficient priviledge to make this change.  At the moment it only affects one [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285711/source-code-on-stack-overflow-cc-by-sa-or-mit), and that question has been migrated away.

Better yet, just remove it.

Comment: Why does this tag even exist? It has one question, that was migrated to MSE about a week ago. Should it have been auto-deleted by now?

Answer (score 1):

I've removed it from the one question it affected. It'll be removed automatically by the system at some point during the next 24 hours.